# Several modes are overriding my custom tabbar-buffer-groups-function :(

Tags: emacs, tabs, customization

I've customized the `tabbar-buffer-groups-function` with limited success, but certain modes often override this. For example, `java-mode` and `thrift-mode` demand that they exist in their own tab groups, but I want them to use the same `"user"` group.

Could someone help me reinforce the desired tabbar groups behavior? Would `...-mode` hooks fix this?

https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs#L142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying the conditions seems to fix the problem.

```
    ;; Tab groups: irc, emacs, user
    (defun tabbar-buffer-groups ()
      (list (cond
             ;; IRC
             ((eq major-mode 'rcirc-mode) "irc")
             ;; Emacs-internal / dired
             ((or (string-match "^\\*" (buffer-name)) (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)) "emacs")
             ;; all other buffers
             (t "user"))))
```

Comment: `tabbar.el` contains a detailed default example for `tabbar-buffer-groups` -- that is usually the best place to start in terms of making your own modifications.

Comment: @lawlist Obviously, but the documentation was *lacking*, so I asked here. Yes, I've tried turning it off and on again!